# Using PYQGIS to join 2 dbf files with common column(id)

Tags: python, join, dbf, qgis

I am new to QGIS and Python. I need to join 2dbf files using QGIS and Python to create a shapefile.The 2 dbf files have a common column(id). Can someone give me an idea how i can join the dbf files to produce 1 shapefile? What library can i use for the same?

Comment: I can also share some sample data if not clear , what is to be done..

Comment: Do you need to carry out this operation periodically? If no, then you can do this job with a DBF editor.

Comment: yes it is a periodic process...

Answer (score 0):

Since there are no other answers, I'll offer my solution with batch joining 2 or more files using [DBF Commander Professional](http://dbf-software.com).

Install the app, then create a BAT file that contains SQL commands as follows:

```
"c:\Program Files\DBFCommander\DBFCommander.exe" -q "INSERT INTO 'D:\destination.dbf' SELECT * FROM 'D:\source.dbf'"
```

Type as much commands as you need, or use a loop to find all DBF files in the folder. Then run the BAT file. Remember, all DBF files should be of the same structure (field names and types).

The app has full-featured 20-days trial period, so you can carry out this operation for free. More info on using DBF Commander Pro in a batch mode you can find [here](http://dbf-software.com/dbf-command-line.html).